# Hide BarButton item from Navigation Controller of TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a tabBarController that contains three tabs. I want  to show rightBarButtonItem to navigation bar only in 1st ViewController but when i am getting back i want it to be visible again. How to achieve this?

I tried to set enabled=NO for the BarButtonItem but the result wasn't good.

I also tried to set BarButtonItem to nil when the view changes but when i get back has disappeared.

I moved BarButtonItem from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear but it did't work properly.

This is the code for rightBarButtonItem into viewDidLoad of first ViewController.

```
UIImage *refreshButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9B_Info.png"];
UIImage *refreshButtonImageB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9A_Info.png"];

UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[refreshButton setImage:refreshButtonImage
               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[refreshButton setImage:refreshButtonImageB
               forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[refreshButton setImage:refreshButtonImageB
               forState:UIControlStateSelected];

refreshButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

[refreshButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(showImageInfo)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *refreshBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:refreshButton];

self.refreshBtn=refreshBarButtonItem;

[self.tabBarController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.refreshBtn];
```

Comment: can you upload a screen shot of your storyboard ?

Comment: I added rightBarButtonItem programmatically.

Comment: Ho right, can you show implementation ?

Comment: Yes i want exactly this.

Comment: @James03 I reedited my post with some code

Answer (score 1):

Do you use storyboard or all in programmatic way ? Try this:

1- open new project ( single view )

2- go into storyboard -> add a navigation controller
[image]

3- delete the table view controller 
[image]

4- set your navigation controller as the start controller ( drag the arrow which points your view controller to your navigation controller )
[image]

5- set your view controller as the root view controller of your navigation controller
[image]
[image]
[image]

6- complete with your codes and @Apurv's solution bellow

Comment: Thanks for your time and tour implementation James. I did not check it but seems to be really good.I posted the code that worked for me in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below line:

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.refreshBtn];
```

With this line:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.refreshBtn];
```

When you want to display it for viewController only, do not add it to tabBarController.

Comment: With this way barButtonItem does not appear at all.

Comment: Are you setting any custom image to UINavigationBar?

Comment: Yes @Apurv.I have custom image for navigationBar

Comment: That is because you don't have any navigation controller, try to add one and use this solution

Comment: Then create a Navigation Controller first. And add it as to you tab controller array.

Comment: Where have i to create Navigation Controller? TabBarController is into a Navigation Controller.

Comment: Why don't you simply use storyboard or xib to manage your viewcontrollers workflow ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes up with this in future this worked for me:

In first view controller i added this to viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"!!!!");

    UIImage *refreshButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9B_Info.png"];
    UIImage *refreshButtonImageB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9A_Info.png"];

    UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [refreshButton setImage:refreshButtonImage
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [refreshButton setImage:refreshButtonImageB
                forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [refreshButton setImage:refreshButtonImageB
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    refreshButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

    [refreshButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(showImageInfo)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *refreshBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:refreshButton];

    self.refreshBtn=refreshBarButtonItem;

    [self.tabBarController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.refreshBtn];



}
```

And in second View Controller in viewWillAppear method this:

```
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
```

The problem is that viewDidLoad of each viewController into TabBarController is called only once but viewWillAppear every time that viewController comes up.

Comment: You do not need to use this hack, it's dirty way to handle your issue.. See apple's doc by looking for navigation controller + nav bar , hope that helps ;)

Comment: Why is this hack? Some issues need creativity and fantasy and i think that it is not a hack.

Comment: Also if you observe my code is similar with @Apurv answer but with tabController implementation.